# Size consume by including php, html, css, external files

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When we include js, css or html files in the website of support 40kb will it add 40 kb extra space to the website ? Also, if we have a file called style.css which has 100 styles and if we  need only one style from that does my page take full size of the file.

I want to include one style file and one js file on every page of my project and these files has all the css and js files already included init. Does all my project page will have the addiction size of all files attached to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when the page is loaded, it loads all of the associated resources (scripts, CSS, images etc) that are called in the code, even if it only needs to use 10% of the defined styles or scripts.

However, consider that once someone loads your 40kb stylesheet once, it's probably cached by their browser, so every other page they visit will not have to redownload that file.

You can minify both JS and CSS in order reduce the filesize.  Also, it's often better to have a single compressed CSS file of a larger size than several smaller CSS files since it's usually ideal to minimize the number of HTTP requests sent every time someone visits your site.  Same with JS, and even images to some extent (a single HTTP request for a sprite that can be used for several different "images" on the page, like icons for example, is better than having independent requests for them all individually).

Comment: so they have to load my attached files only once... I means js or css or html. Or is it only style file ??

Comment: Most browsers (unless users have settings disabling it) will cache CSS, JS, images and other types of resources, then just load them from the local cache rather than redownloading every time they visit the page.  Caches generally have expiry values, so if they haven't visited in a month or two it may be redownloaded, but generally speaking browsers take advantage of the cache when possible.

Comment: Note that pages dynamically generated by PHP or another server-side script are not cached (although static HTML pages may be), so for example if you're using Wordpress they might have the CSS, JS, images cached but not the page markup itself.  This can be addressed by using a server-side caching system though.

Comment: I am not disturbing any check setting by coding, as per your answer I do not have to worry as all the caching will will take care by browser. Is it correct ??

Comment: Yes, generally speaking browsers are pretty smart about caching content (of course some users may have caching disabled but that is not common).  It's still good practice to minify your CSS and JS into a single CSS and a single JS file, and if you run into bandwidth issues you may want to consider a caching/CDN service like CloudFlare.

Comment: @user2841252 If this answer helped please mark it as the accepted answer btw :)

Comment: thank u dear for ur response .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the downloaded data will be whatever is included in your external files. Also, if you ever do have a situation where you have multiple external CSS files, it's a good idea to try and compose it into one file to minimize HTTP requests. It's not a huge gain in performance, but every little bit may help. It's the same idea as including all your sprites in a single image file. There's some more information on it here if you're interested: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Yes**

If you add 40KB of css to your website, it will increase the data downloaded by your users by 40KB and will increase your server storage space usage by 40KB.

Even if you only need to use one style from the css file, it will still require downloading the whole 40KB .

To reduce the amount of data that needs to be downloaded, you could use a CSS minifier like [the YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/). If you don't need certain files on certain pages, just don't include them. If you're really looking to decrease the size of your webpage, you could use something like [Google's PageSpeed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service) or [Apache mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module). You can even use an [online analyzer](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to see how to improve the speed of your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

If you are including a file to make use of it, the whole file will need to be downloaded.

Best way to check out your size (not exact but fast) is to save the webpage from your browser, this will include all the images/css/js in a folder next to the page file. Check out their filesize to know how big the page takes.